# convert dask dataframe column to string

Tags: python, pandas, dask

```
import pandas as pd                                                 
                                                                    
data = {"calories": [420, "hi", 390], "duration": [50, 40, 45]}     
                                                                    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)                                             
                                                                    
df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1)
```

I want to convert the calories column to string.

So here is my try

```
df = df.astype({"calories": "string"})

df
Dask DataFrame Structure:
              calories duration
npartitions=1
0               string    int64
2                  ...      ...
Dask Name: astype, 3 tasks

df.set_index("calories")
TypeError: Cannot interpret 'string[python]' as a data type
```

Is there a way I can pass in the datatype for all the columns and convert them to the desired datatype ?
Like say I want to convert many columns to strings and some of them to date and few to bools.

I know the column names and the data type.
And want Dask to honor them.

TypeError: Cannot interpret 'string[python]' as a data type

Comment: you didn't assign it back: `df  = df.astype({"calories": "string"})` ?

Comment: When i try to set the key I am getting an error TypeError: Cannot interpret 'string[python]' as a data type. Thanks for taking a look at the problem

Comment: You're Welcome. Maybe a version problem then. For me assigning your code to the original df works. Check your version v/s when was the `string` dtype introduced - guessing this

Comment: I am using Python 3.10 and dask version seems to be (2022.2.1) lol not sure what's wrong here.

Comment: not sure but I have `2021.04.0` version of dask and it works(df  = df.astype({"calories": "string"})). Maybe string dtype was introduced in later versions? Not sure just guessing I dont work with dask actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with **lambda** function.

```
import pandas as pd                                                 
                                                                    
data = {"calories": [420, "hi", 390], "duration": [50, 40, 45]}                                                                  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)                                             
df['calories'] = df['calories'].apply(lambda x: str(x))                                                               
print(df)
for column in df.columns:
    print("Column ", column, "is dtype:", df[column].dtype.name)
```

**Output**

```
  calories  duration
0      420        50
1       hi        40
2      390        45
Column  calories is dtype: object
Column  duration is dtype: int64
```

**Edit**
If you want to convert all the columns of the data frame to string, you can use **applymap**.

```
import pandas as pd                                                 
                                                                    
data = {"calories": [420, "hi", 390], "duration": [50, 40, 45]}                                                                  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)                                             
df = df.applymap(str)
for column in df.columns:
    print("Column ", column, "is dtype:", df[column].dtype.name)
```

**Output**

```
Column  calories is dtype: object
Column  duration is dtype: object
```

Or using **lambda** and **applymap**

```
import pandas as pd                                                 
                                                                
data = {"calories": [420, "hi", 390], "duration": [50, 40, 45]}                                                                  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)                                             
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x[0] if type(x) is list else None)
for column in df.columns:
    print("Column ", column, "is dtype:", df[column].dtype.name)
```

**Output**

```
Column  calories is dtype: object
Column  duration is dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi Is there a way to convert all the columns to string ?

Comment: all dataframe to string ?

Comment: All the columns of the data frame to string lol :)

Comment: check my update

Comment: Thanks I used your idea and it kind of worked .Thanks again for taking your precious time out and taking a look at this in the first place

Answer (score 1):

It seems the error happens when you call `set_index` and Dask is not able to recognize `"string"` as valid data type when [setting the new partition divisions](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/main/dask/dataframe/partitionquantiles.py#L417). Instead you can use `str`, e.g. `ddf = ddf.astype({"calories": str})`. Here's a complete reproducible snippet:

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
                                                                    
data = {"calories": [420, "hi", 390], "duration": [50, 40, 45], "other_col": range(3)}                               
df = pd.DataFrame(data)                                          
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

ddf = ddf.astype({"calories": str}).set_index('calories')
ddf.compute()
```

Comment: Yes thanks a ton for the help you are right about it